# Does a character get their STR bonus to the Bite attack granted by a Ring of Rat Fangs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, ability-scores, natural-weapon

I'm pretty sure I know the answer, but I'd like a few other people to take a look just to be sure.

The entry for the Ring of Rat Fangs states:

> The wearer gains a bite attack as a primary natural attack. This attack deals 1d4 points of piercing damage for a Medium wearer or 1d3 points of damage for a Small wearer.

The fact that the entry specifies it is a *primary* natural attack tells me that it does in fact use the characters full Strength bonus to damage (in addition to being an attack at their full BAB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creature will deal its normal bite damage due to the [*ring of rat fangs*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-rat-fangs) plus the creature's full Strength bonus when the creature uses *only* its natural attacks. The Universal Monster Rules on [natural attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks) says

> Primary attacks are made using the creature’s full base attack bonus and add the creature’s full Strength bonus on damage rolls.

However, this changes if the wearer of the *ring of rat fangs* also makes attacks with weapons. The Universal Monster Rules continue, saying that

> **Creatures with natural attacks and attacks made with weapons can use both** as part of a full attack action (although often a creature must forgo one natural attack for each weapon clutched in that limb, be it a claw, tentacle, or slam). Such creatures attack with their weapons normally **but treat all of their available natural attacks as secondary attacks during that attack**, regardless of the attack’s original type.

So, just biting and clawing and tentacles and whatever other natural attacks you possess? Full Strength bonus. But biting *and* swinging a sword? Normal sword attacks, but the bite attack suffers a −5 penalty on the attack roll and deals its 1d3 or 1d4 points of damage plus only ½ the creature's Strength modifier.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I'll have to remember the clause about mixing it with weapon attacks. I was thinking of using the ring to add another attack for a natural weapon-focused catfolk, so I can still theoretically get all 3 attacks as long as I only use claws and forgo manufactured weapons.